# difference between System.out.println() and System.err.println()

Tags: java, println, system.out, system.err

What is the difference between `System.out.println()` and `System.err.println()` in Java?

Answer (score 86):

In Java `System.out.println()` will print to the standard out of the system you are using. On the other hand, `System.err.println()` will print to the standard error.

If you are using a simple Java console application, both outputs will be the same (the command line or console) but you can reconfigure the streams so that for example, `System.out` still prints to the console but `System.err` writes to a file.

Also, IDEs like Eclipse show `System.err` in red text and `System.out` in black text by default.

Comment: Also, System.out is buffered, and System.err is not

Comment: Not dissing your answer but it's normally referred to as standard out and standard error (stdout/stderr) rather than standard out and error out. +1 by way of apology in advance since, other than that nitpick, you're correct.

Comment: You are right, but I couldn't by god remember the right names... Using C# has clearly been bad for my low-level programming skills

Answer (score 41):

System.out is "standard output" (stdout) and System.err is "error output" (stderr). Along with System.in (stdin), these are the three standard I/O streams in the Unix model. Most modern programming environments (C, Perl, etc.) support this model.

The standard output stream is used to print output from "normal operations" of the program, while the error stream is for "error messages". These need to be separate -- though in most cases they appear on the same console.

Suppose you have a simple program where you enter a phone number and it prints out the person who has that number. If you enter an invalid number, the program should inform you of that error, but it shouldn't do that *as the answer*: If you enter "999-ABC-4567" and the program prints an error message "Not a valid number", that doesn't mean there is a person named "Not a valid number" whose number is 999-ABC-4567. So it prints out nothing to the standard output, and the message "Not a valid number" is printed to the error output.

You can set up the execution environment to distinguish between the two streams, for example, make the standard output print to the screen and error output print to a file.

Comment: I think this is the best answer, as it explains the meaning of the streams.

Answer (score 4):

Those commands use different output streams. By default both messages will be printed on console but it's possible for example to redirect one or both of these to a file.

```
java MyApp 2>errors.txt
```

This will redirect `System.err` to `errors.txt` file.

Comment: `java MyApp 2>errors.txt` what is `2 >` and how it works? can you explain?

Answer (score 2):

`System.out`'s main purpose is giving standard output.

`System.err`'s main purpose is giving standard error.

---

Look at these

http://www.devx.com/tips/Tip/14698

http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_Where_does_System.out_and_System.err_output_go%3F

Answer (score 1):

`System.out.println("wassup");` refers to when you have to output a certain result pertaining to the proper input given by the user whereas `System.err.println("duh, that's wrong);` is a reference to show that the input provided is wrong or there is some other error.

Most of the IDEs show this in red color (`System.err.print`).

Answer (score 1):

this answer most probably help you it is so much easy
`System.err` and `System.out` both are the same both are defined in `System` class as reference variable of `PrintStream` class as
`public final static PrintStream out = null;`
 and 
`public final static PrintStream err = null;`

means both are ref. variable of `PrintStream` class. 
normally `System.err` is used for printing an error messages, which increase the **redability for the programmer.**

A minor difference comes in both when we are working with **Redirection** operator.

Answer (score -3):

It's worth noting that an OS has one queue for both System.err and System.out. Consider the following code:

```
public class PrintQueue {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
            System.out.println("out");
            System.err.println("err");
        }
    }
}
```

If you compile and run the program, you will see that the order of outputs in console is mixed up.

An OS will remain right order if you work either with System.out or System.err only. But it can randomly choose what to print next to console, if you use both of these.

Even in this code snippet you can see that the order is mixed up sometimes:

```
public class PrintQueue {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("out");
        System.err.println("err");
    }
}
```

Comment: "An OS has one queue for both `System.err` and `System.out`." That's a very general and not necessarily accurate statement. On what basis do you make that statement? [Citation needed]

In a console application (such as `cmd` or `terminal`), both streams ("queues" as this answer calls them) appear to be merged (because they show in the same terminal emulator), but they are actually separate.See [Difference between `stdout`, `stderr` and `stdin`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3385261/2225787) for details.