# python http status code

Tags: python, http-status-codes, httpconnection

I'm writing my own directory buster in python, and I'm testing it against a web server of mine in a safe and secure environment. This script basically tries to retrieve common directories from a given website and, looking at the HTTP status code of the response, it is able to determine if a page is accessible or not.
As a start, the script reads a file containing all the interesting directories to be looked up, and then requests are made, in the following way:

```
for dir in fileinput.input('utils/Directories_Common.wordlist'):

    try:
        conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(url)
        conn.request("GET", "/"+str(dir))
        toturl = 'http://'+url+'/'+str(dir)[:-1]
        print '    Trying to get: '+toturl
        r1 = conn.getresponse()
        response = r1.read()
        print '   ',r1.status, r1.reason
        conn.close()
```

Then, the response is parsed and if a status code equal to "200" is returned, then the page is accessible. I've implemented all this in the following way:

```
if(r1.status == 200):
    print '\n[!] Got it! The subdirectory '+str(dir)+' could be interesting..\n\n\n'
```

All seems fine to me except that the script marks as accessible pages that actually aren't. In fact, the algorithm collects the only pages that return a "200 OK", but when I manually surf to check those pages I found out they have been moved permanently or they have a restricted access. Something went wrong but I cannot spot where should I fix the code exactly, any help is appreciated..

Answer (score 2):

I did not found any problems with your code, except it is almost unreadable. I have rewritten it into this working snippet:

```
import httplib

host = 'www.google.com'
directories = ['aosicdjqwe0cd9qwe0d9q2we', 'reader', 'news']

for directory in directories:
    conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(host)
    conn.request('HEAD', '/' + directory)

    url = 'http://{0}/{1}'.format(host, directory)
    print '    Trying: {0}'.format(url)

    response = conn.getresponse()
    print '    Got: ', response.status, response.reason

    conn.close()

    if response.status == 200:
        print ("[!] The subdirectory '{0}' "
               "could be interesting.").format(directory)
```

Outputs:

```
$ python snippet.py
    Trying: http://www.google.com/aosicdjqwe0cd9qwe0d9q2we
    Got:  404 Not Found
    Trying: http://www.google.com/reader
    Got:  302 Moved Temporarily
    Trying: http://www.google.com/news
    Got:  200 OK
[!] The subdirectory 'news' could be interesting.
```

Also, I did use [HEAD](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec9.html#sec9.4) HTTP request instead of GET, as it is more efficient if you do not need the contents and you are interested only in the status code.

Comment: Thanks a lot, I'll make it more readable then and I'll try to solve the issue looking at your implementation.

Comment: I'm trying to use the example you just showed me, when I make requests to Google I get always: 400 bad request while using your code I get the status code you've written in this post..dunno what is wrong..maybe I'm missing something somewhere..if you want to take a look at the core part of the code is here: [link](http://pastebin.com/VaAb18uX)

Comment: I took your script and start playing around with it, I've changed the way how the directories are retrieved and I used: "for directory in fileinput.input('utils/Directories_Common.wordlist'):" since I've all the directories listed in that file..with this modification I always get a 400 bad request...

Comment: I can give no further advice unless I know exactly what it in the 'utils/Directories_Common.wordlist' file and what output do you get. Are you sure your URLs return different codes? Try to test it using this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6136861/325365

Comment: That file contains a list of all the directories to look up, one entry for each line..

Comment: I've found out that if I use a vector, containing all the directories, it works better, but I can't insert almost 1 hundred of directories in a vector, I'd like to use a separate file..

Comment: I've fix all by scanning the directories file and populating an array with a directory for each element of the vector. It was the way in which I retrieved the directories that caused problems..

Comment: Despite this, when I use HEAD method instead of GET, I always get 400 bad request..I fixed even this one, when importing the directories there was still present the new line char and this caused some issues..

Comment: Maybe it is not supported well by your server. Feel free to use GET instead.

Answer (score 1):

I would be adviced you to use http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/# for http.