# 500 + Website Check in Python for multiple status

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-3.x, url, http-headers

- I know there are multiple question for url checks. I am very new to
  python so trying to understand from multiple posts and searching for
  new library for help as well. I am trying to work for below point for
  internal as well as external websites.  :

  ```
     Status Code
     Status Description
     Response Length
     Time Taken 
     Websites are like ,, www.xyz.com , www.abc.log , www.abc.com/xxx/login.html and more combinations. Below is the
  ```

  initial code ..

  ```
  import socket
  from urllib2 import urlopen, URLError, HTTPError

  import urllib
  socket.setdefaulttimeout( 23 )  # timeout in seconds
  #print "---------URL----------", " ---Status Code---"
  url='https://www.google.com'

      try :
        response = urlopen( url )
      except HTTPError, e:
          print 'The server couldn\'t fulfill the request. Reason:', str(e.code)
          #Want to get code for that but its not showing

      except URLError, e:
          print 'We failed to reach a server. Reason:', str(e.reasonse)
          #Want to get code for that but its not showing


      else :

          code=urllib.urlopen(url).getcode()
          **#here getcode is working
          print url,"-------->", code
          #print 'got response!'
  ```
- I want to check if website exists or not first . Then will go for
  rest of checks as above mentioned. How to organise this to work for
  all the above points for 500+ urls. Do I need to import from txt file
  ? Also one more point  I have seen that if www.xyx.com is working and
  www.xyz.com/lmn.html do not exists, it is still showing 200 .

Answer (score 1):

I think you can the page presence with this code:

```
import httplib
from urlparse import urlparse

def chkUrl(url):
    p = urlparse(url)
    conn = httplib.HTTPConnection(p.netloc)
    conn.request('HEAD', p.path)
    resp = conn.getresponse()
    return resp.status < 400

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print chkUrl('http://www.stackoverflow.com') # True
    print chkUrl('http://stackoverflow.com/notarealpage.html') # False
```

Comment: Ok. But how to combine it with my code and also the points I mentioned .
 . Your code is good to check for, if website exists or not.But I am really looking for more points :). If web is down I want to getcode and status . More like that for all below :
 Status Code
   Status Description
   Response Length
   Time Taken

Comment: Do you want to know the server is serving, I think for this you need cURL and if you get a response then it is. Here with the url of pycurl : http://pycurl.io/

Comment: I want to check if URL is up or not with its status code and description. Its response length and time taken .

Comment: I want to check and print those things.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15968031/python-http-status-code this link might help you out.

Comment: OK.I'll go through it.  Also for all d web I will be trying to import it from some text file. Need to check for response time as well. Let's see if someone help us with better solution. Till then I will read as much I can

Comment: Ok.. If you need the reponse time you can use this code : import requests;r = requests.get('http://xxxxxxxx.org/'); r.headers;                             you can see the time taken with the attribute '"x-runtime"