# how crawl an URL through shell scripting?

Tags: shell, scripting, web-crawler

I have to check a server is up or not by Firing certain URL.
 I tried using wget command,where there is a response like "HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK "
is coming which shows the server is  up and running.but i cant return the status to make it automate.
I have a list of 10 URL which i have to nake it automate to check all the URL are responding properly or not.
please help.

Comment: You should take a look at [ask] and [mcve]

Comment: You can consider to use curl - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6136022/script-to-get-the-http-status-code-of-a-list-of-urls

Comment: After running the command check the exit code. A non-zero value indicates failure.

Answer (score 0):

This is literally it:

```
if curl https://example.com
then
    echo "up"
else
    echo "down"
fi
```