# Trying to call an url of service in docker with bitbucket pipelines

Tags: docker, curl, wget, bitbucket-pipelines

I am trying to test if my service running in docker container well, so I want to call url 'http://localhost:3000/test' and check if it is 200. In all other cases I want to fail my bitbucket pipeline.

So at first I have tried to curl it, but I dont get any output or error.

```
curl -f "http://localhost:3000/test" || exit 1
```

But it passes it anyway, even if url is bad or container is not running at all.

Then I have tried to call `wget` right in container but I doesn't succeed too.

```
docker exec -ti -t -i mycontainer sh -c "wget http://localhost:3000/test || exit 1" || exit 1
```

It fails on `the input device is not a TTY`

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Please also provide your pipeline config

Comment: @SvenHakvoort unfortunately I cant do it. In this step I am simply run some containers in my network and then trying to get my url.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simpler solution that I suggested in the comments of the other answer. If all you want to do is exit the script on error, you can simply test for the exit status:

```
$ wget -q --spider http://localhost:3000/ || exit 1
```

Heck, if you want more control, and error reporting you could even test the exit status using `$?`. Wget returns quite information exit statuses. Quoting the manual here:

> EXIT STATUS
>          Wget may return one of several error codes if it encounters problems.
>
> ```
>    0   No problems occurred.
>
>    1   Generic error code.
>
>    2   Parse error---for instance, when parsing command-line options, the .wgetrc or .netrc...
>
>    3   File I/O error.
>
>    4   Network failure.
>
>    5   SSL verification failure.
>
>    6   Username/password authentication failure.
>
>    7   Protocol errors.
>
>    8   Server issued an error response.
>
>    With the exceptions of 0 and 1, the lower-numbered exit codes take precedence
>    over higher-numbered ones, when multiple types of errors are encountered.
> ```

Answer (score 0):

First remove `-ti -t -i` since in a pipe there is no tty device (terminal). (`-ti` is the same as `-t -i`)

Now your script can check if the url is reachable or not, to check for a 200 response code, use

```
wget -q --spider --server-response 'http://localhost:3000/' "${url}" 2>&1 | diff -q <(echo 200) <(awk 'NR==1{print $2}')
```

the first part is well explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53358157/4980651), then `diff` to see if the response code is 200.

Your final command looks like

```
docker exec mycontainer sh -c "wget -q --spider --server-response 'http://localhost:3000/' "${url}" 2>&1 | diff -q "echo 200" <(awk 'NR==1{print $2}') || exit 1"
```

EDIT

diff is a bit overkill here, so try this

```
wget -q --spider --server-response 'http://localhost:3000/' "${url}" 2>&1 | [ code`awk 'NR==1{print $2}'` == code200 ] || exit 1
```

The prefix "code" is used to suppress the warning when wget can't connect, awk will return nothing causing `[ ]` to complain.

Comment: So it failed with ```Usage: diff [-abBdiNqrTstw] [-L LABEL] [-S FILE] [-U LINES] FILE1 FILE2
Compare files line by line and output the differences between them.
This implementation supports unified diffs only.``` My images is based on node:10.12 and may be that it doesn't have this functionality.

Comment: Why use diff when you can simply check the return code when you use wget in --spider mode? If the file exists, it will return 0, else 8 if it was a 404 or any other server error.

Comment: @darnir I've tried but it returns a lot of things, even with `wget -nv --spider 'http://localhost:3000/' ` I got
`2018-11-30 17:42:05 URL: http://localhost:3000/ 200 OK`
`

Comment: No, you just need to do `wget --spider http://localhost:3000/ || exit  1`. You could check for the exit code using `$?` and see if you only want to exit on a server error or other errors as well.

Comment: You are totally right! Much cleaner, I guess the only advantage of mine is it does not print out anything.

Comment: @Siyu: Sure, just add a `-q` to the command line I provided. See the answer I wrote