# Where should I use command-line arguments instead of Scanner?

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I know that when you create your `main` method of a `Class` in `Java` you create it as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
```

I also know that the `array` of `Strings` named `args` it's used to enter command-line parameters in the `main` method but I develop my applications on `Eclipse` and I never had used it because I always have entered my values by `Scanner`.

It is a bad practise to use `Scanner` instead of command-line parameters? Has `args` array another purpose? When should I use `args` array?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you mean you are asking for args using `Scanner` once your program is ran?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In reverse order:

> When should I use `args` array?

When you are passing command-line parameters.

> Has `args` array another purpose?

No. It's for passing command-line parameters.

> Is it a bad practise to use `Scanner` instead of command-line parameters?

It's not always possible to use a `Scanner`. A `Scanner` might read from STDIN, but in many UNIX systems it is prefered to read command input from STDIN and use command line arguments for program *options* (e.g. `--help` or `-h`).

Comment: Hi `Elliott`, I never had heard about `STDIN` (Thanks for add a new concept for me) and I saw this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385201/confused-about-stdin-stdout-and-stderr to search about it but I'm still a bit confused. It is a type of file? I also saw on `Wikipedia`: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams that `it's a stream data going into a program` (I think this should be the definition that you refer to) but I still have a doubt. Is it only the concept of a stream data (in general) or is it another method of enter parameters into my program? Thank you again!

Comment: In java, that is System.in which is where I assumed your hypothetical Scanner would be reading.

Comment: Yes, I use my `Scanner` with `System.in`. Then, `STDIN` it's just a general concept to refer a `stream data going into a program` but not a method to get this goal, right? And it varies by the programming language, right?

Comment: No. It's the standard input mechanism on most operating systems. It might be a pipe or file, or user input.

Comment: I'm sorry if I'm getting a wrong idea about it but... then `System.in` it's the same than `STDIN`?

Comment: `System.in` reads from `STDIN`. `System.out` writes to `STDOUT`. In Java.

Answer (score 0):

`Scanner` and the parameter for `main` are two completely different things. A scanner can be used to ask the user for some kind of action. The parameters for `main` are relevant when you want to launch the jar either from another application or via commandline. Cooked down: whether to use `Scanner` or parameters is rather a question of the design of the software, not coding-style.

Answer (score 0):

It entirely depends on your circumstances. Ask yourself the question: "Where are the values coming from? What is the best way for my program to receive these values?"

If the answer is "a user", then prompting the user, thereby guiding the user to the values needed, is likely the best answer.

Any other answer means the values are likely coming from some automated process, which means that "prompting" is a bad choice. Now there are suddenly a lot of choices, again controlled by your circumstances:

- Command-line arguments
- Configuration file
- Data file (e.g. CSV file)
- Network communication (e.g. web service)
- Database
- ... and many more

Sometimes a combination is appropriate, e.g. a *command-line argument* to find the *configuration file*, which may include a directory to scan for *data files*.

You can even do both "prompting" and command-line arguments. If all needed values are supplied as arguments, use them, otherwise prompt for the missing values. Providing no arguments would then prompt for all values.

Comment: Correct me if I'm missing something but if I enter command-line arguments have to be at the same time I run the program? Or could it be whenever I want?

Comment: If the program is executed by a shell script (e.g. a .bat file on windows), then you write the command-line arguments in the script, not when you "run" the script. Same if executed by another program. This is the "not a user" scenario, because the user running the script is not supplying the values (unless the script supply *it's* arguments to your program).

Comment: So, when I run my program on Eclipse at the same time a .bat file will be executed at the same time? (Of course I should configurate both programs to connect each other before running them, I guess) I'm sorry but I have some concepts in the air yet. And another question: the .bat file would be used if I know what parameters have to been used on my program? Something like a test with fixed values?

Comment: No, you generally don't run a shell script from Eclipse. If you want to supply command-line arguments when running from Eclipse, specify them on the Arguments tab of the Run Configuration. A .bat file *may* be used when running from a command prompt or windows shortcut on the desktop/menu.

Comment: Ok now I think that I understand it. So in Eclipse add the arguments on the Arguments tab it's the same as command-line arguments on the Windows console, right? And what do you mean with desktop/menu? Thank you!