# Why is tqdm output directed to sys.stderr and not to sys.stdout?

Tags: python, stdout, stderr, sys, tqdm

Accordingo to the python [python documentation concerning sys.stdou and sys.stderr](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html):

> stdout is used for the output of print() and expression statements and for the prompts of input();

> The interpreter’s own prompts and its error messages go to stderr.

Nevertheless, according to the documentation ot [tqdm](https://tqdm.github.io/docs/tqdm/) the default output is sys.stderr.

I am confused on why this would be the case given that it does not seem to be related to the interpreter own prompts or error messages. What am I missing? Why is tqdm output directed to sys.stderr and not to sys.stdout?

Edit: I think that the discussion here sort of answers this:
[When to use sys.stdout instead of sys.stderr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35461687/when-to-use-sys-stdout-instead-of-sys-stderr)

Answer (score 4):

Redirecting progress bar to `sys.stderr` makes `tqdm` [more powerful in command line](https://github.com/tqdm/tqdm#module). For example, consider this command

```
$ time find . -name '*.py' -type f -exec cat \{} \; | tqdm | wc -l
```

Simply inserting `tqdm`(or `python -m tqdm`) between pipes will pass through all `stdin` to `stdout` while printing progress to `stderr`. This makes piping easier because `tqdm` does not alter the `stdout` of one command allowing us to use `wc -l` in the same chain.