# child_process exec command is getting executed multiple times

Tags: javascript, electron, child-process

I am using `exec()` to run a terminal command to show dialog in electron mac application.

**The code I am using:**

```
var exec = require('child_process').exec;
var request = require('request');

request('https://server_url', function (error, response, data) {

    console.log("inside request");

    exec(`osascript -e 'with timeout of 86400 seconds
                                    tell app "System Events"
                                        display dialog "` + data.pop_up_message + `" buttons {"OK", "Cancel"} 
                                    end tell 
                                end timeout'
    `, function(error, stdout, stderr){

        console.log("inside exec");

    });

});
```

Its showing multiple dialogs in a single request.

**Console output:**

```
inside request
inside exec
inside exec
inside exec
```

Here `'inside request'` is getting printed only once. But the `'inside exec'` is getting printed multiple times. 
What is the reason for this issue. How can I solve this.

Comment: *inside exec* is printed every time the callback for `exec` is called ... not whenever exec is called .... hmmm, which should only happen once anyway - how odd

Comment: Yes. The dialog is shown multple times. When I am clicking the dialog buttons the 'inside exec' is printed

Comment: would be more interesting to log the values of error, stdout and stderr each time to see what is happening

Comment: I have logged error values too. But its showing empty string

Comment: and what about the stdout and stderr values then

Comment: error null, 
stdout button returned:Ok, 
stderr

Comment: These are the outputs of each parameters

Comment: error and stderr are null. stdout returns error 'button returned:Ok'

Comment: is it always 3 times?

Comment: Yes. All the three are shown multiple times

Comment: I was referring to the question ... do you always get inside request x 1 followed by inside exec x 3 .... that **exact** pattern?

Comment: inside request only once. inside exec is not exactly 3 times. sometimes it shows twice, sometimes 3 times or multiple times

Comment: Which version of nodejs, and are you using the "builtin" child_process or is that an external library?

Comment: I am using the built in child_process library and Node version 4.4.5

Comment: how odd - that should not be happening at all

Answer (score 0):

The inner function is a callback that is connected to 2 streams: `stdout` and `stderr`. The third parameter is an error object that typically contains something if the child process failed or timed out (see: [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback)).

Whenever you exec something, his output will arrive after some time by sending messages through one of these. It can happen quite shortly after, or a very long time after. Also, it can be a rather small or big output, so this will come into chunks of data depending on what the execution does. The "under the hood" of `stdout` and `stderr` can be easier to visualize in the C / C++ perspective.

Let's say that you write a C program that prints to console every 5 seconds by writing to `stdout` and then you call it with your NodeJS module.

Your `console.log` here will print something as soon as it detects a message being sent through one of these streams. In that specific case, it will print every 5 seconds.

Just a small picture, since there could be a lot more to say about what streams are and how they work. [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385201/confused-about-stdin-stdout-and-stderr#answer-3385261) adds some interesting details about them.

---

**Update - 29/18/2016:**

Updated the streams part. Like Jaromanda X suggested, error isn't a buffer but rather and Error object.

Comment: error isn't a stream, is it? I know what stdout is, I know  what stderr is ... but error? [documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) doesn't say anything about being called for each stream - in fact, there are no streams involved ... just an Error object and two Buffers

Comment: You might be right. Im still looking for an evidence on what it is exactly. I think this is a message that NodeJS sends himself, which is (I think) a stream. It would be interesting to clarify this.

Comment: I won't take a chance on this, an error object is safer for now. Thanks for pointing this out! Will update.

Comment: But not only the 'inside exec' is running multiple times. The dialog is also shown multiple times. So the exec command is also running multiple times.