# Python: output to multiple redirects

Tags: python, output

In C++, I can output to `cout` and `cerr`; in practice this results in code wherein I can redirect output to two files at once like:

```
./some_program > first_file.something 2> second_file.else
```

How would I accomplish this in python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

E.g. in Python 3, just import the equivalents of `cout` and `cerr`, namely `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr`.

```py
from sys import stdout, stderr

print('to standard output', file=stdout)
print('to standard error', file=stderr)
```

Then you can use your bash redirection as you normally would:

```sh
python program.py 1>output 2>errors
```

And if you want, you can even name them whatever you like. E.g.:

```py
from sys import stdout as cout, stderr as cerr

print('to standard output', file=cout)
print('to standard error', file=cerr)
```

It's less "Pythonic," but if it helps you bridge the gap from your C++ experience, it may be a help.

Answer (score 1):

https://docs.python.org/3/library/sys.html

```
sys.stdout
sys.stderr
```

[confused about stdin, stdout and stderr?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385201/confused-about-stdin-stdout-and-stderr)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to redirect from the command line, it's pretty much the same way you would do in C++:

```
python file.py > first_file.txt 2> second_file.txt
```

Programmatically, you can do this with `sys.stdout` and `sys.stderr`, by monkey patching those with files of your choice.