# Shell - echo some command (curl) vs type the command in the terminal

Tags: shell, curl, echo

Why am I not getting the same result when I do :
1. Go to my terminal and enter

```
curl -I www.httpbin.org
```

Result :

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Connection: keep-alive
Server: meinheld/0.6.1
Date: Wed, 20 Dec 2017 19:20:56 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: 13011
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
X-Powered-By: Flask
X-Processed-Time: 0.00580310821533
Via: 1.1 vegur
```

2. Create a file `APIConnection.sh`
Containing :

```
#! /bin/bash

api_url_1="www.httpbin.org"

echo `curl -I $api_url_1`
```

Then go to my terminal and execute the file : `./APIConnection.sh`
Result :

```
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                             Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
  0 13011    0     0    0     0      0      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--     0
  Via: 1.1 vegurme: 0.0147929191589 true
```

Comment: Remove the `echo` from the script and you will get the same result

Comment: @Zlemini, ...not *quite* the same -- whether stdout is to the TTY matters.

Comment: @NicolasN, ...there are arguably two separate questions in here: One, why `echo $(...)` puts all the output from `...` on one line -- this one is absolutely a FAQ; covered in [BashPitfalls #14](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#echo_.24foo), and also by running your code through http://shellcheck.net/. Two, why the percentage/status bar is only present in one case and not the other. That's a `curl`-specific question (though several other programs also make distinctions in their default output based on `isatty()` results, and thus will have their own variances in similar conditions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for which a progress bar is only displayed when running `curl` between backticks is explained in `man curl`:

> PROGRESS METER
>
> ```
>    curl normally displays a progress meter during operations,
>    indicating the amount of transferred data, transfer speeds
>    and estimated time left, etc. The progress meter displays
>    number of bytes and the speeds are in bytes per second. The
>    suffixes (k, M, G, T, P) are 1024 based. For example 1k is
>    1024 bytes. 1M is 1048576 bytes.
>
>    curl displays this data to the terminal by default, so if you
>    invoke curl to do an operation and it is about to write data
>    to the terminal, it disables the progress meter as otherwise
>    it would mess up the output mixing progress meter and
>    response data.
> ```

If you want to turn off the progress meter explicitly, this can be done with `--silent`.

``` `` ``` is legacy syntax for [command substitution](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Command-Substitution.html) in bash and other POSIX-compliant shells. This means that output is captured by the shell, not written directly to the terminal. Because `curl` cannot detect that it would later be written to the terminal by `echo`, it does not disable the progress meter as described above.

If you really do want to use a command substitution here (instead of just having your script run `curl -I "$api_url_1"` without any command substitution *or* echo), put quotes around your command substitution to avoid string-splitting and glob expansion.

It's also advisable to use the modern command substitution syntax, `$()`, so each substitution has its own quoting context:

```
echo "$(curl --silent -I "$api_url_1")"
```

Answer (score 0):

executing `curl -I www.httpbin.org` gives you the result of the standard output while executing `` echo `curl -I $api_url_1` `` gives you the result of the standard error.
To see the differences execute the following command and then look at the content of created `se.txt` and `so.txt` files:

```
 curl -I www.httpbin.org 1>so.txt 2>se.txt
```

look at [about stdin, stdout and stderr](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385201/confused-about-stdin-stdout-and-stderr) for more information.

Comment: It's untrue to say that the version with `echo` and a command substitution emits only stderr -- the stdout is written into the FIFO, string-split and glob-expanded, and then passed to `echo` as arguments. Some of it may be overwritten by the progress bar on `stderr` moving the cursor back to the end of the line and thus not rendered, but *some* content from stdout is absolutely present (and visible in the OP's stated output).