# Alternative to System.out to display error messages in a console based application

Tags: java, console-application, system.out

I am developing a console based application.

Is it a good idea to use System.out.println() to display error messages on the console? I am using a lot of these in my classes for error handling.

My class looks something like this:

```
public void validatePlayerSelection(String playerSelection, List<String> listOfIndex) {
    try {
        if (playerSelection == null || playerSelection.isEmpty()) {
            throw new NullPointerException();
        } else if (Integer.parseInt(playerSelection) < 11
                || Integer.parseInt(playerSelection) > ((size * 10) + size)) {
            System.out.println("The input you have entered cannot be found on the board");
        } else if (listOfIndex.contains(playerSelection)) {
            System.out.println("Cell already taken. Please select a different move.");
        } else {
            flag = false;
        }

    } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
        System.out.println("The input must be a number on the board");
    }
}
```

What is the alternative to System.out.println? Also, is this an efficient way to write code?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you can also use `System.err` for errors. For console applications these messages will generally show up in the same place. Also see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3385261/7470253)

Answer (score 3):

No. You use the console for small things, like: experimental code.

As soon as we are talking *anything* to be used in the real world, you look out for using some sort of Java logging framework.

For example [log4j](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/), or using the built-in [logging](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/Logging/article.html) facilities.

Seriously, even when you just create your own little command line helper tools: learn how to use a logging framework, and use it. You want for example to be able to emit messages dependent on some sort of **logging level** (think: verbose, info, warnings, errors). If you not use an existing framework, you will inevitably start to create your *own* framework at some point. Repeating all the mistakes than you can make while doing so, for no reason at all (besides the learning experience).

Also understand: logging isn't the same as "user interaction". All the things your example does are about getting information from the user (or giving him some responses/feedback). For **that**, you use the most appropriate path (which could be system.out). But for anything "else" that your application might want to "log" - you better look out for alternatives than system.out resp. system.err.

Comment: But it is a simple console application. So won't System.err or System.out  be efficient to display error messages to the user?

Comment: @Vishakha Many many many things started "as a simple thing". Therefore people started off with something insufficient. Thing is: *anything* that is useful (for you or others) tends to **grow**. And then, after you invested a lot of time, you find: "it is just such a pain how this things logs information" - but then you will have to make changes to in zillions of places. Again:  *any* java developer should know how to do proper logging. You have to learn it anyway. So learn it now, and practice using it.

Comment: I don't think log is the place where program results are stored. Abstracted output is one thing, but only having output to logs is another one entirely.

Comment: @M.Prokhorov True, I updated my answer a bit to better fit that distinction.