# What is the stdout output?

Tags: stdout, stderr

Newbie; I'm learning the Linux cmd line and one of my questions is; "inside the ‘stream-redirection’ folder there is a program called ‘program’. When you run this it will output to stdout and stderr. What is the stdout output??? I'm unsure how to read the output and even where it is?? 
I've tried 
./program 1> stdout **then** cat stdout 
I'm lost and I have to do the same with stderr.

Comment: It's not very clear what you are asking about. Could you please try to reformulate your question? Maybe also have a look at these: [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_streams#Standard_output_(stdout)), [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3385201/confused-about-stdin-stdout-and-stderr#3385261)? Do they answer your question?

Comment: This is the exact question I have got to answer. Inside the ‘stream-redirection’ folder there is a program called ‘program’. When you run this it will output to stdout and stderr. What is the stdout output? it's part of a Lab with immersiveLabs.